# Why angularjs' transclude causes cells separation (double borders) in a table?

Tags: css, angularjs, html-table, cell

See directive below that will create a table with four columns:

```
app.directive('tableWrapper',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<table><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></table>',
  }
});

app.directive('myCells',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<tr><td>Name</td><td ng-repeat="c in [1,2,3]">{{c}}</td></tr>',
  }
});
```

Here is html (see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTrSifnYWKaNy9XQzfGL)

```
<table><tr><td>Name</td><td ng-repeat="c in [1,2,3]">{{c}}</td></tr></table>
<hr/>
<table-wrapper><my-cells></my-cells></table-wrapper>
```

Both are building same table, yet the second one, because of transclude, creates separated cells.

So instead of: |Name|1|2|3|
The second displays: |Name||1||2||3|
Where || is textual representation of thick border drawn with borders of adjacent cells.

What is the reason for that?
What could be the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transclude 'table' does not have `border-collapse: collapse` because it does not match the

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse
}
```

rule in `normalize.less`

If you look at the dom structure below you can see why. Your transclude 'table' is actually being rendered as a `table-wrapper` element instead of a table

[image]

Comment: Whoa - why is my `<table></table>` taken away?!

Comment: I see. I have used `<table ng-transclude="">...</table>` instead, and I have also added `required: true` in the `myCell` directive. Thank you for your help and directing me to that answer!